# How to Receive FileResponse of pyramid into ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pyramid

I have pyramid code that sends `fileResponse` which is PDF.  Now, I want to write Ajax code that will receive this response and open that PDF in new window, like this: `window.open(filename);`

This is my code:

```
filepath = ("ledgerReport.pdf")
    response = FileResponse(filepath)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ("attachment; filename=ledgerReport.pdf")
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't well suited to an AJAX flow - `window.open` is used to open an URL in a new window, not for displaying data available in Javascript (and please don't repost questions).

The proper way to do implement this as a new window is to use `window.open` with a URL to the controller delivering the response:

```
window.open("/pdfs/pdf_id")
```

.. or you can use `target=` on the link to make the link open in a blank window.

If you want to deliver the PDF inside your regular UI (instead of in a different window) use an iframe.